# Input state field depending on drop-down selection

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

**Need to accomplish**: When a user selects anything other than CA, print the selected state inside the notice that I have below.

```html
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md">
            <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Select state of residence.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                This feature is not available at this time for <b>[State]</b> residents.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the portion that prints out the states:

```
<option value="<?= $abbr; ?>"><?= $state; ?></option>
```

How would I be able to target to print it out inside the [State] portion depending on what the drop-down selection is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Martinho said, adding an id to the `<b>` makes changing the value a lot easier - I've also added one to the warning itself so you can easily hide / show it, as well as adding an inline style to hide the warning on load

You can use an eventListener on the select to listen for the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event - Each time the event is fired, we'll use an if statement to check if the selected value is 'CA' or not, and then update the appropriate elements *( Hide the warning if it is, display the warning with the correct text if not )*

```js
document.getElementById('resident').addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value !== 'CA') {
    document.getElementById('stateWarning').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#stateWarning b#stateName').textContent = this.value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('stateWarning').style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md">
    <label for="resident">I am a resident of:</label>
    <select class="custom-select" id="resident" required>
      <option value="">Choose...</option>
      <option value="CA">CA</option>
      <option value="MT">MT</option>
      <option value="TX">TX</option>
      <option value="WA">WA</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Select state of residence.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-3">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div id="stateWarning" class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none;">
      This feature is not available at this time for <b id="stateName">[State]</b> residents. For more information about our privacy practices, please visit our <a href="<?= $config->get_url('policy'); ?>" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Light, however, whenever I select a state, all that I get is an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` warning.

Comment: Are you adding the id 'stateWarning' to the 'alert alert-danger' div?

Comment: You are right, I was missing that! Thanks so much @Light.

Comment: Everything is working great, but it's selecting the 'AK' abbreviation instead of 'Arkansas', is there a way to target that? @Light

Comment: it gets the text it inserts from the `value="xx"` atrribute on the option tag - is that the issue? If you can't change what the value attribute is being set to, you could use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].text` instead of `this.value` to get the textContent of the selected element

Comment: You are awesome, works like a charm! Got the 'Arkansas' now. @Light

Answer (score 0):

You coud simply use JQuery to achieve what you want.

But first you should assign an id to your 'b' tag to simplify the code. Lets assume that the id  is 'state'.

```
$("#resident").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != 'CA'){
       $("#state").text($(this).val());
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this @Martinho, I haven't done jQuery in a while, how would I be able to call it inside the alert?

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't explain myself right. You simply paste the JQuery code inside a script tag in your file and it should work